# What is the standard way to halt a VHDL testbench after a certain time period?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, simulation

In Verilog I can use the $finish function to halt the simulation, but my search for the similar option in VHDL has failed so far.

The closest solution that I found online is to use this code in my VHDL testbench:

```
stop_simulation :process
begin
   wait for 1000 ns; --run the simulation for this duration
   assert false
       report "simulation ended"
       severity failure;
end process ;
```

How do you set the time for your simulation in VHDL? For example if I want my clock to run for 10 us, then what is the STANDARD option to achieve this?

Comment: hi ehsan . if u wanna make halt in simulation you should use  wait for 1000 ns; it's work fine.and if you're persian i can help you easily.

Comment: Yes I am Iranian. So that code is the STANDARD way to halt the simulation in VHDL?

Comment: That's not the STANDARD way but it works and it's the recommended way in at least one textbook (Janick Bergeron, "Writing Testbenches"). Nowadays you'd just call `std.env.stop;` instead (and set the compiler options to VHDL-2008).

Comment: Just put a wait; statement after a wait for ... s; statement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two ways are commonly used:

**Stop the clock** (or clocks). That way there are no more events, and the simulation stops. Sometimes, there is a signal (for instance called `done`) that turns of the clock generator. The testbench asserts the `done` signal when all tests are completed.

**Report a failure**. This is not so elegant, but many people use it. A severity of failure will cause the simulator to stop.
`report "simulation finished successfully" severity FAILURE;`

**Stop procedure** A third way, only available since VHDL 2008 is to call the procedure `stop`, in the `env` package of the `std` library. For instance, like this: `std.env.stop;`

Comment: How does the simulator observe the `done` signal? You've missed the point of the question, I think.

Comment: Once all clocks are stopped and no event is triggered anymore, simulation becomes infinitely fast. An arbitrary long simulated time can be used.

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding the `std.env.stop` method from @BrianDrummond comment above.

Comment: @scary_jeff I've updated the answer to include std.env.stop. Haven't seen this used "in the wild" yet, but I agree that this is the most elegant way to stop the simulator.